# Write a simple bootloader that reads user's name

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, osdev, minix

I'm trying learn how operating systems work. This is an easy task I'm having a hard time solving: to write a simple bootloader that prompts the user for his name and prints a welcome message, like "hello, >>name<<" - after that, it does nothing.

I'm running `minix 3` with `qemu`, if this is of any relevance. I simply compile an `asm` file and `dd` its first 512 bytes to `/dev/c0d0` (the virtual hard drive of `minix`).

I can print the message and print what the user is typing. However, I didn't manage to print the user's name afterward.

Here is my assembly code:

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

mov si, HelloString
call print_string
mov di, name
call read_name
mov si, name
call print_string

read_name:
    read_char:
        mov ah, 0h  ; read character from keyboard
        mov [di], ah    ; save it in the buffer
        inc di      ; next char
        int 0x16    ; store it in AL
        cmp ah, 0x0d    ; check for enter
        je stop_reading 
        mov ah, 0eh     ; display character in AL
        int 0x10    ; echo it
        jmp read_char   ; an so on
    stop_reading:
        mov si, EoL
        call print_string
        ret

print_char:
    mov ah, 0x0e    ; one char
    mov bh, 0x00    ; page number
    mov bl, 0x07    ; font color
    int 0x10
    ret

print_string:
    next_char:
        mov al, [si]
        inc si
        or al, al
        jz exit_function
        call print_char
        jmp next_char
    exit_function:
        ret

;data
HelloString db 'Enter your name', 0xd, 0xa, 0
name times 20 db 0
EoL db 0xd, 0xa, 0

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0;
dw 0xaa55
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll want to review something like Ralph Brown's interrupt list for [Int 0x16/ah=00](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1754.htm) . In particular _AH_ will have the Keyboard scan code. If you want the ASCII character it is actually in _AL_. I think you want to do `cmp al, 0x0d` instead of `cmp ah, 0x0d`

Comment: You're storing 0's into the buffer at `name`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. Ross and I have pointed some out in the comments. You should read my [General Bootloader Tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/3857942). Although not related to your actual problem you should set up *DS* (and *ES* if you eventually need it) to 0 because you use an origin point of 0x7c00 (`org 0x7c00`). You should also set up the stack somewhere you know your code won't be clobbering. I'd add this code to the top before:

```
    mov si, HelloString
    call print_string
```

Change it to be:

```
    xor ax, ax         ; AX=0
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax         ; SS=ES=DS=0
    mov sp, 0x7c00     ; Place stack before the bootloader. Grows down from 0x0000:0x7c00

    mov si, HelloString
    call print_string
```

After your code is finished running you should place the CPU in an infinite loop so that it doesn't continue by executing your functions beneath the main code. So before the label `read_name:` place an infinite loop. Something like this is typical:

```
    cli                ; Turn off interrupts        
endloop:
    hlt                ; Halt processor until next interrupt encountered
    jmp endloop        ; Jump back just in case we get an MNI (non-maskable interrupt)
```

You have some bugs in your `read_char` function. One of the best places for BIOS Interrupt information is [Ralph Brown's Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm). [Int 0x16/AH=0](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1754.htm) is documented as:

> ```
> AH = 00h
>
> Return:
> AH = BIOS scan code
> AL = ASCII character
> ```

You should be using the ASCII character in *AL* to store into your string buffer. You should also be comparing *AL* with 0x0d, not *AH* (Which is the keyboard scan code, NOT the ASCII character). You also are storing data into your string buffer before you read the characters with `int 0x16`. You need to put them in the buffer after. When you reach `stop_reading:` you will want to place a NUL (0x00) character at the end of the buffer.

Your code for `read_name` could look like:

```
read_name:
read_char:
    mov ah, 0h  ; read character from keyboard
    int 0x16    ; store it in AL
    cmp al, 0x0d    ; check for enter
    je stop_reading
    mov [di], al    ; save it in the buffer
    inc di      ; next char
    mov ah, 0eh     ; display character in AL
    int 0x10    ; echo it
    jmp read_char   ; an so on
stop_reading:
    mov byte [di], 0x00    ; NUL terminate buffer
    mov si, EoL
    call print_string
    ret
```

The revised bootloader could look like:

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

    xor ax, ax         ; AX=0
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7c00     ; Place stack before the bootloader. Grows down from 0x0000:0x7c00

    mov si, HelloString
    call print_string
    mov di, name
    call read_name
    mov si, name
    call print_string

    cli                ; Turn off interrupts        
endloop:
    hlt                ; Halt processor until next interrupt encountered
    jmp endloop        ; Jump back just in case we get an MNI (non-maskable interrupt)

read_name:
read_char:
    mov ah, 0h         ; read character from keyboard
    int 0x16           ; store it in AL
    cmp al, 0x0d       ; check for enter
    je stop_reading
    mov [di], al       ; save it in the buffer
    inc di             ; next char
    mov ah, 0eh        ; display character in AL
    int 0x10           ; echo it
    jmp read_char      ; an so on
stop_reading:
    mov byte [di], 0   ; NUL terminate buffer
    mov si, EoL
    call print_string
    ret

print_char:
    mov ah, 0x0e       ; one char
    mov bh, 0x00       ; page number
    mov bl, 0x07       ; font color
    int 0x10
    ret

print_string:
next_char:
    mov al, [si]
    inc si
    or al, al
    jz exit_function
    call print_char
    jmp next_char
exit_function:
    ret

;data
HelloString db 'Enter your name', 0xd, 0xa, 0
name times 20 db 0
EoL db 0xd, 0xa, 0

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0;
dw 0xaa55
```

---

I highly recommend using [*BOCHS*](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) to debug bootloaders. It has a built in debugger that understands real mode and real mode addressing and is better suited for debugging bootloaders than *QEMU*

Comment: Great answer, indicated much more than I expected. Could you please recommend some relevant literature on assembly programming and its usage in os development?

Comment: The best place for OS Development from an assembly language perspective would be [OS Dev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) . It's not an assembly reference but the tutorials are almost entirely assembly language.